# Taking 6 people from 8 married couples where there is exactly one married couple

Tags: combinatorics

I have read almost identical problem in ["Taking 4 people from 6 married couples with exactly one married couple selected"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1607851/if-4-people-are-chosen-are-chosen-out-of-6-married-couples-what-is-the-chan) but I don't quite understand.

I modify the problem by increasing the taken people and available married couples as follows.

> How many way are there to take 6 people from 8 married couples such that there is exactly only one married couple in the 6 people?

## My attempt

- There are ${8\choose 1}= 8$ ways to choose the exactly one married couple. Two people are already selected. I need to take 4 people more.
- For every 2 married couples there are 4 possibilities to take 2 people who are not a married couple. So there are ${7\choose 2} \times 4$ ways to choose 2 more people. We still need 2 people more.
- With the same argumentation as the second point above, there are ${5\choose 2} \times 4$ ways to choose 2 remaining people.

As a result, there are ${8\choose 1}\times {7\choose 2} \times {5\choose 2} \times 4 \times 4 =26880$ ways.

However, could you tell me whether my answer is correct?

Comment: I think it should be $\binom{8}{5} \times \binom{5}{1} \times 2^4$.

Comment: @Zenix: I just understood your argumentation.

Comment: The first correct answer will always win. It is fair enough, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to select one married couple, which, as you say, can be done in $\binom{8}{1}$ ways.  We also need to choose four more people, with one each from four of the remaining seven married couples.  Choose which four of those seven couples will have a representative in $\binom{7}{4}$ ways.  For each such couple, there are two ways to select the representative from that couple.  Hence, there are $$\binom{8}{1}\binom{7}{4}2^4 = 4480$$
ways to select six people from eight married couples such that there is exactly one married couple among those six people.

Comment: Thank  you very much. I need a couple of hours to determine the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are very close. I would say:

1. First we need to choose which married couple is included in its entirety. There are $8 \choose 1$ options for this $=8$ .
2. Now we will choose $4$ married couples from which we will just take one person. So we are picking $4$ couples from the remaining $7$. This is $7 \choose 4$ or $35$.
3. Finally, in each of the $4$ there are two ways of choosing which member of the couple we include so we multiply by $2^{4}=16$.

$8 \times 35 \times 16 = 4480$.

Do we believe this? Well let's do a sense check.

How many ways are there to choose $6$ people from $16$? $16 \choose 6$ = $8008$.

So the probability of getting one married couple is $4480/8008 = 0.56$ Yeah, I buy that, as in it is not over $1$ or under $0.1$

Comment: A nice proof for my mistake.

Comment: You were very close to being exactly right AND you have us all an interesting problem to discuss!

Answer (score 2):

Choose $5$ soloists from the $8$ couples: $\binom{8}{5}2^5=56\cdot32=1,792$.

Choose $1$ from the $5$ soloists to be re-united: $\frac52$ as the soloist never was.

Answer: $4,480$.

(or, 5 couples from the 8, then 'the' couple and 4 soloists)

Your method is wrong as you have double-counted.

Comment: A very interesting perspective!

Comment: Yes. I just realized that I have used permutation in my previous calculation.

Comment: Liked your first answer !